# Neutral wire in red-black cable (Canada)?

Tags: electrical, neutral

I have a bunch of 10/2 cable with red and black (plus ground) wires in Canada (from a removed air conditioner). It's perfectly good cable, so I'd like to repurpose it in a few spots on 15 or 20 amp circuits in my home (despite being overkill). Is there a problem using this cable despite the absence of a white wire? If so, should I use the black as live and the red (perhaps with white electrical tape) as neutral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...and that's why red-black cable is not a thing in the USA.

Nope. Don't think you can.  In Canada, neutral wires smaller than #2 must have a native white or gray jacket. Their "cannot re-identify" rules are even tougher than NEC.

You can use it for old-school switch loops, if those are legal in CA.